# Convert to INNER JOIN syntax instead of WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to convert the following SQL query using `INNER JOIN` syntax to reduce execution time but I have a problem implementing `OR` (CASES)

Original SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.couponid, c.branchid, c.chainid
FROM `users_roles` a, `field_data_field_ypefthinos` b, `custom_redemptions` c, `field_data_field_chain_manager` e, `field_data_field_node_tax_inception` f, `field_data_field_brand_manager` j, `field_data_field_brand_node_ref` k, `field_data_field_product_ref` i, `field_data_field_company_manager` z, `field_data_field_brand_company` t
WHERE
(a.rid = 4
AND a.uid = ?
AND b.field_ypefthinos_uid = a.uid
AND b.entity_id = c.branchid)
OR
(a.rid = 5
AND a.uid = ?
AND e.field_chain_manager_uid = a.uid
AND e.entity_id = f.entity_id
AND f.field_node_tax_inception_tid = c.chainid)
OR
(a.rid = 9
AND a.uid = ?
AND j.field_brand_manager_uid = a.uid
AND j.entity_id = k.field_brand_node_ref_nid
AND k.entity_id = i.field_product_ref_nid
AND i.entity_id = c.couponid)
OR
(a.rid = 6
AND a.uid = ?
AND z.field_company_manager_uid = a.uid
AND z.entity_id = t.field_brand_company_nid
AND t.entity_id = k.field_brand_node_ref_nid
AND k.entity_id = i.field_product_ref_nid
AND i.entity_id = c.couponid)
```

In process of convert:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.couponid, c.branchid, c.chainid
    FROM `custom_redemptions` AS c
(INNER JOIN `field_data_field_ypefthinos` as b
    ON b.entity_id = c.branchid
INNER JOIN `users_roles` as a
    ON b.field_ypefthinos_uid = a.uid
    WHERE a.rid = 4
    AND a.uid = 351)

OR

(INNER JOIN `field_data_field_node_tax_inception` AS f
    ON f.field_node_tax_inception_tid = c.chainid
INNER JOIN `field_data_field_chain_manager` AS e
    ON f.entity_id = e.entity_id
INNER JOIN `users_roles` AS a
    ON e.field_chain_manager_uid = a.uid
    WHERE a.rid = 5
    AND a.uid = 351)

OR
(INNER JOIN `field_data_field_product_ref` AS i
    ON i.entity_id = c.couponid
INNER JOIN `field_data_field_brand_node_ref` AS k
    ON k.entity_id = i.field_product_ref_nid
INNER JOIN `field_data_field_brand_manager` AS j
    ON j.entity_id = k.field_brand_node_ref_nid
INNER JOIN `users_roles` AS a
    ON j.field_brand_manager_uid = a.uid
    WHERE a.rid = 9
    AND a.uid = 351)
OR
(INNER JOIN `field_data_field_product_ref` AS i
    ON i.entity_id = c.couponid
INNER JOIN `field_data_field_brand_node_ref` AS k
    ON k.entity_id = i.field_product_ref_nid
INNER JOIN `field_data_field_brand_company` AS t
    ON t.entity_id = k.field_brand_node_ref_nid
INNER JOIN `field_data_field_company_manager` AS z
    ON z.entity_id = t.field_brand_company_nid
INNER JOIN `users_roles` AS a
    ON z.field_company_manager_uid = a.uid
    WHERE a.rid = 6
    AND a.uid = 351)
```

What's wrong with my code?

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: INNER JOIN, or old explicit join (comma separated tables) have the same performance.

Comment: You can't have different INNER JOIN's OR-ed. (Try UNION ALL instead.)

Comment: And inner join is not going to help.  You have a bunch of cartesian products going on.  I would start over, thinking about what you really need and possibly using `union all` to bring the tables together.  Your query seems quite needless complicated.